# Selenium scripts will run successfully on different versions of windows OS?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, functional, windows

I have some selenium scripts for my project. I have developed and tested on windows 7 OS.But I would like to know whether these same scripts will run successfully on different versions of windows OS like windows 8, 8.1 and windows 10 etc..If not please let me know the reason behind in it.

Please share your ideas and experiences.

Comment: Try running the scripts from the same machine by connecting other machine via hub to the other nodes in selenium Grid

Comment: I am not looking for executing those on different machine.I would like to know whether it will make any difference or not ?

Comment: It will not make a difference when you have the appropriate drivers installed in the local machine

Comment: Currently I am using latest chrome driver and latest chrome browser.Will same drivers work on windows 10 ??

Comment: Selenium script have different behavior on different OS not different flavor. As I have run script with same configuration in Win 7 and Win 10, Its running same in both the OS. Now the configuration need to be same for both PC, like Java version, exe files, Selenium version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course.. I have experience on that some times i write some scripts on windows 7 environment and run it on windows 10 environment.it works perfectly.

But you need to give attention for one reason that is if you using jar files or libraries when creating script you need to configure that files in your running environment also when or before running the scripts.

(Actually i did not test my scripts with windows XP environment. but in windows 7,8,8.1 and 10, scripts execute perfectly for me.)